# What are the advantages of creating pojo classes for Json response in android?

Tags: android, json, api

We can also use json response directly so what is the need of converting them in pojo classes

Comment: Readability and maintainability

Comment: you get an _object_ to work with. Instead of parsing string constantly

Comment: This can also help to stream large JSON data with libraries like GSON

Comment: but converting json response to models can be time consuming while we can also direct parse data from json so what is the advantage of conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly interact with the service, Dao, without any type checking. And this brings the application of Jackson API in spring.

So that every request can be easily handled as Models.

Comment: but converting json response to models can be time consuming while we can also direct parse data from json so what is the advantage of conversion?